# Data source query callback problems (call order, ability to change global variables)

Tags: javascript, web-services, rally

I've reduced my code to the following short example.  In it, I want to query for a set of iterations, and then in the callback, loop over the iterations and sum the resources.  There is a global variable in which I'd like to store the sum... but I can't get this to work.

The specific problem is that the query (and associated callback) are run after the other processing.

```
<html><!-- COMMENT -->

    <meta name="Name"    content="YOUR APP NAME HERE" /> 
    <meta name="Version" content="0.1" /> 
    <meta name="Vendor"  content="YOUR COMPANY NAME HERE" /> 

<!-- Rally SDK --> <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.25/sdk.js"></script>

<!-- App script -->  <script> 

var rallyDataSource; var resourceSum = -1; 

function ProcessIterations(results) {
    alert("In ProcessIterations");  
    var resourceSum = 0; 
    for (iIter = 0; iIter < results.iterations.length; iIter++) {
      var iteration = results.iterations[iIter] ;
      resourceSum += iteration.Resources; 
    }
    alert("In ProcessIterations, resourceSum="+resourceSum);   }

function queryError () {
    alert("A query error occurred");   }

function runMainQuery() {   var today = dojo.date.stamp.toISOString(new Date(), {milliseconds: true, zulu: true});

  var queryObject = {
    key: "iterations",
    type: "Iteration",
    fetch: "Name,ObjectID,Resources,Project",
    order: "EndDate asc",
    query: "(Project.ObjectID != \"__PROJECT_OID__\")"
    };

  rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, ProcessIterations, queryError); }


function Main() {   rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__", "__PROJECT_OID__",
                "__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__", "__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");

  runMainQuery() ;

  var tableConfig = {
      'columnKeys'   : ['planEst'],
      'columnHeaders': ['Plan Estimate']   };   var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(tableConfig);   table.setCell(0,0,resourceSum) ;   table.display("app_div");  

}

rally.addOnLoad(Main);

</script> <body>
    <div id="app_div"></div> 
    <div id="error_div"></div>  </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be a little tricky to get the hang of asynchronous callbacks but you're really close.
Basically if you just move the creation of your table from Main to up in your ProcessIterations callback you should be good:

```
function ProcessIterations(results) {
    alert("In ProcessIterations");  
    var resourceSum = 0; 
    for (iIter = 0; iIter < results.iterations.length; iIter++) {
      var iteration = results.iterations[iIter] ;
      resourceSum += iteration.Resources; 
    }
    alert("In ProcessIterations, resourceSum="+resourceSum);   }

    var tableConfig = {
      'columnKeys'   : ['planEst'],
      'columnHeaders': ['Plan Estimate']   };   
      var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(tableConfig);   
      table.setCell(0,0,resourceSum) ;   
      table.display("app_div"); 
}

function Main() {   
    rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__", "__PROJECT_OID__",
            "__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__", "__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");
    runMainQuery() ;
}
```

That way you won't display your table until the data is available from your rallyDataSource.findAll call and your resourceSum has been calculated.

As an additional resource checkout some of the examples in our help documentation on using RallyDataSource and async callbacks:
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rally-data-source

Comment: I am aware that things work if the table render is issued from within the callback.  I actually deliberately implemented things this way to hear/learn about the issues re. queries.

In our particular (more complex) case, we actually have an initial query (for iterations/projects) and in its callback we do 2 things: add table entries AND issue another query (for stories in iteration/project) who's callback makes additional table entries (the sum of all plan estimates), once per entry in set of results from the initial query.

We can't make table entries from within both of the nested queries.

Comment: It sounds like you have your callbacks chained together correctly.  Waiting to call table.display() until all your data has been added may help...  You can always post another question with more complete code as well.